# Google Sheets Query function sort

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I am trying to sort some deposits, I have a list of Dates in Column A,
Payment methods in column B, and Amounts in column C.

I need to create a query that can give me Column A "Dates", Column B "Cash Amounts", Column C "Card Amounts", and Column D "Paypal".

Here is a screenshot showing expected results.
The columns A:C, are what I have.
The columns in blue E:H are what I would like the query to display.

[image: 0]

Comment: This will be a pivot table or pivot query. I guess if you have 2 transactions of the same type on the same day, you would want them added up?

Comment: The columns A:C are already a query from the raw data of every transaction. So this set in A:C are already daily amounts. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try it like this:

```
=QUERY(A1:C6, "select A,sum(C) where A is not null group by A pivot B", 1)
```

[image: 0]